# I can't render Google map on the my Flutter Android app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to render a simple Google map on my Android app. I have enabled Google Map API and used it in `AndroidManifest.xml`. And also updated it in `pubspec.yaml` file and `buid.gradle`. But whatever combination I try I am not getting map on the screen.
I have went through various website to solve but still didn't.

Every time `pubspec.yaml` it get like this:

```
[demo] flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
  google_maps 6.3.0 (7.0.0 available)
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.0 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.0 (10.0.4 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.3 available)
  leak_tracker_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.1 available)
  meta 1.11.0 (1.12.0 available)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
  vm_service 13.0.0 (14.0.0 available)
Got dependencies!
8 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try flutter pub outdated for more information.
exit code 0
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  LatLng _center = const LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060); // New York City coordinates
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("my_marker"),
          position: _center,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: "Flutter Google Map",
            snippet: "Created by you!",
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My Google Map'),
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
          markers: _markers,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="demo"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="API_KEY"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
             
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
name: demo
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.3.0 <4.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

A simple Google map on the screen.

Comment: Did you make sure that you have set up your API keys correctly? https://developers.google.com/maps/flutter-package/config#step_4_add_your_api_key_to_the_project

Comment: API key was correct but there was some problem with flutter version which was 19 . I tried downgrading it to 16 and it worked